# Do Luis support pre-built location entities?

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I want to add a pre-built entity for `location` in Luis, the strange thing is i couldn't find any. However, if you want to use a pre-built app like `Calendar` there is a `Calendar.Location` field. I then referred to the [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/pre-builtentities) and [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-entities).  The second one implied that, and I quote

> Geography: Existing LUIS apps that use `builtin.geography` will be supported until December 2018.

Does that mean that there is no location entity I can use by itself in Luis currently?

Answer (score 1):

**Datetime**, **Geography** and **Encyclopedia** have been deprecated.

`builtin.datetimeV2` can be used instead of `builtin.datetime` to use Datetime entity. But there is currently no news about Geography and Encyclopedia.